# Submenu is not showing when applying dynamic menu using json angular

Tags: angularjs, json

I am using a json file to show all the menus in my html page. I have applied menus in json file with right process. I am using angular to bind these menus to html page. All the main menus are displaying there. But the issue is when i click on submenu arrow, it is showing blank. Also only one menu item has submenu that is about us menu, but it is showing counter 1 to each menu item. The url to see how it is looking is [dynamic menu using json angular](http://getyourworkdone.in/angular/)

How to apply those submenu to only about us menu and how to display submenus when clicked on about us menu ?

my html code is

```
<nav id="menu" ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="demoCtrl">
        <ul id="my-list">
            <li ng-repeat="menu in menus">
                <a href="{{menu.url}}">
                    {{menu.name}}
                </a>
                <ul ng-show="menu.sub.length!=0">
                    <li ng-repeat="subItem in menu.sub">
                        <a href="{{subItem.url}}">{{subItem.name}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Rest of the source you can find in given url.

Comment: why `menus.sub` and `menu.sub`? do both objects `menus` and `menu` have `sub` property?

Comment: I have edited that thing it is menu.sub only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo link working](https://plnkr.co/edit/R9KAvVl2dW16P20pCLSL?p=preview)

[image: Menu]
[image: Submenu]

In your code the menu script loaded before your angular so the sub data not loaded properly.
change your code like this. set timeout for your script
Changes done Here:-

```
                $(function() {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#menu").mmenu({
                        extensions  : ["widescreen"],
                        counters    : true,
                        navbars     : [{
                            content: ["searchfield"]
                        }, true]
                    }).on( 'click',
                        'a[href^="#/"]',
                        function() {
                            alert( "Thank you for clicking, but that's a demo link." );
                            return false;
                        }
                    );
                    var API = $("#menu").data( "mmenu" );
                    }, 3000);
                });
```

Comment: but home has no submenus then why is this going like about us.

Comment: Ok i have found that. I have to use ng-if instead of ng-show property.